# Possible 2 canvases

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I had my controls on the sprite working until I added the code for a random moving sprite. Here's the code:

```
    self.shape = self.canvas.create_oval(0,0,50,50,fill="grey80")
    self.speedx = (10)
    self.speedy = (10)

    self.enemy1_list = []
    for i in range(1):
        self.enemy1_list.append(self.playWindow())
    while True:
        for self.playWindow in self.enemy1_list:
            self.playWindow.update()
        parent.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)

def update(self):
    if pos[2] >= WIDTH or pos[0] <= 0:
        self.speedx *= -0.5
    if pos[3] >= HEIGHT or pos[1] <= 0:
        self.speedy *= -0.5
```

And I get this error code:

```
AttributeError: 'playWindow' object has no attribute 'playWindow'
```

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough code to help. Do you think that an instance of `playWindow` should itself have an instance of `playWindow`?